# Does Rc::deref return a reference?

Tags: rust

The following code:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let s = Rc::new(String::from("Hello"));
    let o: &String = *s;
}
```

Gives me this error:

```
  = note: expected type `&std::string::String`
             found type `std::string::String`
```

I expected that `*s` would give some sort of reference, because the `deref` signature is `fn deref(&self) -> &T`.

One thing that confuses me is if I change the `let o` line to this:

```
let o: String = *s;
```

I now get an error of `cannot move out of borrowed content`.

So I have two related questions

1. Why does `*s` for Rc values not return a reference?
2. I understand how references cannot be moved, how is `*s` a borrow, but not a reference? I thought these words meant the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*s` doesn't expand to `s.deref()`, it expands to `*(s.deref())`. That's because the `*` operator's primary function is to dereference pointers. Intuitively, you would expect `*s` to not return a pointer (unless `s` was a pointer to a pointer) whether `s` is a normal pointer or a smart pointer. This expansion preserves that intuition.

Comment: Ah thanks! And to explicitly answer the second question, `*(s.deref())` is not allowed because `s.deref()` is borrowed (a reference).